# Removing Empty Strings from Text File (Not Lists) in Python 3

Tags: python, editor

[Sample Text 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WZxC.png) is the excerpt output of some text I'm trying to format (wouldn't let me paste it directly in original format or attach img). Output is generated from the following:

```
fhandle = open('legalcode.txt')
for line in fhandle:
    line = line.strip()
    print(repr(line))

hold = input()
```

Line 2 of my output is just empty, and it looks like I'm getting empty strings as well? I'm looking for clarification on what that empty space is on Line 2 and recommendations on removing the empty strings. All current search results only discuss string removal from lists.

Thank you in advance for the assist.

**EDIT 1**

I've used the following to remove the ' ' as discussed:

```
fhandle = open('legalcode.txt')
for line in fhandle:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.strip('\r')
    if line == '':
        continue
    print(repr(line))
```

But as you can see in [Sample Text 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWYtE.png) there is still an unidentified space on the third to last line. Is there an alternative method of showing hidden characters?

**EDIT 2**

The text file I'm working from: https://github.com/Achulhu/Legal-Code-Reformat

The original text can be found at: https://www.ilga.gov/legislation/ilcs/ilcs5.asp?ActID=3992&ChapterID=35

**EDIT 3**

I integrated @Arseniy's recommendation for [ord] with the current run through:

```
fhandle = open('legalcode.txt','r')
for line in fhandle:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.strip('\r')
    if line == '':
        continue
    print(repr(line),[ord(c) for c in line])
```

However, [ord] is not giving that space an identification ([Sample Text 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf2WJ.png)). For clarification, I am using Windows OS and calling it from Command Prompt. It was written in ATOM, and I've tried running it through IDLE as well to see if that made a difference.

Comment: The quotes are there because you used `repr()`, which specifically puts quotes around strings.  Why are you using `repr()` if you don't want that behavior?

Comment: Repr() is only being used to show me what is there. Those spaces exist regardless.

Comment: In those cases, `line` is an empty string, because the file had a blank line.  Do you want to remove the blank lines from the actual file, or just skip printing them in the loop?

Comment: Eventually, I will have them removed, but for right now I just trying to understand the difference between Line 2 and Line 4 of my output. I have added:

  ***  if line == ' ':
        continue ***

and that solves Line 4 however it does not solve Line 2 of the Sample Text. :(

Comment: The first line looks like it's cut off -- it ends with a double-quote but it does not start with one.  Also the second line doesn't have quotes at all, which is not consistent with `repr()`.  Are you sure that screenshot is accurate?

Comment: This is a small excerpt from a much larger body of text, so the screenshot does cut off the beginning of the first line and the end of the last. But that blank line you see is as-is.

Comment: Those mystery blank lines may be caused by the previous line being exactly 80 characters long, and so there is no room to print the carriage return on the same line, and it carries over onto the next line.  Can you try running that script inside a wider terminal window?

Comment: Hadn't considered that, unfortunately it doesn't appear to be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simply :

```
fhandle = open('legalcode.txt')
for line in fhandle:
    line = line.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')
    line = line.strip()
    print(repr(line))

hold = input()
```

Comment: Yes, I just added a GitHub link to the original post. Please let me know if you have any issue accessing as I've never used GH before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
fhandle = open('legalcode.txt')
for line in fhandle:
    if not line.strip():
        continue
    print(line.strip())
```

Or

```
fhandle = open('legalcode.txt')
lines=[l.strip() for l in fhandle.readlines() if l.strip()]

for l in lines: 
   print(l)
```

Comment: Still getting blank lines with this. :(

Comment: Tried your 2nd option also after the edit, the issue remains.

Comment: Hm. I checked this code on your sample)  I think, that on your platform (m.b. windows?) some characters was not removed by strip method.  let's check it with this code
```
fhandle = open('legalcode.txt')
for line in fhandle:
    if line.strip():
        continue
    print([ord(c) for c in line])    
```


This code will print an integer representing of remaining symbols.

Comment: I just updated the original post with your recommendation. I ran your [ord] code by itself and it came back with no spaces, but when run together it still shows the spaces but without an association for the space...